# How do I fix "Empty message" being sent to the console when sending a message to the discord channel - Python discord bot

Tags: python, discord

I am creating a discord bot in python, but I get the "Empty message" when I try to type any of the commands on my server, I tried asking chatGPT but it didnt help, for example:
vaclavak#notshowingmytag said: '' (bot-testing)
Empty message

Here is my code:

bot.py:

```
import discord
import responses
import random


async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.handle_response(user_message)
        if response:
            await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)
        else:
            print("Empty message")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'the token is here, not gonna show it lol'

    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        # Make sure bot doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        # Get data about the user
        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        # Debug printing
        print(f"{username} said: '{user_message}' ({channel})")

        # If the user message contains a '?' in front of the text, it becomes a private message
        if user_message.startswith('?'):
            user_message = user_message[1:]  # [1:] Removes the '?'
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

    client.run(TOKEN)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_discord_bot()
```

main.py:

```
import bot




if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

responses.py:

```
import random


def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()
    if p_message == 'hello':
        return 'Hey there!'

    if p_message == 'roll':
        return str(random.randint(1, 6))

    if p_message == '!help':
        return "`This is a help message that you can modify.`"
```

I want the bot to respond properly

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the message content, you need to enable the `message_content` intent ([read more](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html)).
So, if you make this small change your code should work:

```py
def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'the token is here, not gonna show it lol'

    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
    ...
```

Make sure you have authorized the privileged message content in the developer portal.

Comment: I have already solved this by adding the intents, but thanks for the answer!